# Autopair parenthesis with cdlatex

Tags: latex, init-file, completion

I'm trying to write my configuration for the first time and I am facing the problem with cdlatex completion of parenthesis conflicting with tools like autopairs. What happens is that, inside a TeX buffer, autocompletion of everything but "(" works: all the symbols "[", "{", and even the dolar sign for math insertion are working.

The `C-h k (` command says that "(" runs the cdlatex-pbb (Insert a pair of parens, brackets or braces), but it says the same for "{" and "[". Also, "C-h m" tells me that the minor mode "smartparens" is active, however `turn-off-smartparens-mode` does nothing.

Inside my `init.el` I have

```
(electric-pair-mode 1)
(setq electric-pair-pairs '( (?\" . ?\") (?{ . ?}) (?( . ?)) (?[ . ?])))
(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)
```

for electric pairs, if that's somehow contributing to the problem, and

```
(smartparens-global-mode 1)
(remove-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'smartparens-mode)
```

However turning off the smartparens-global-mode still does nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour! The reason is described in the docstring for `cdlatex-paired-parens`:

> I recommend to set this to `'$[{'` as these have syntactical meaning in TeX and are required to be paired. `TAB` is a good way to move out of paired parens.

This did it for me: putting

```
'(cdlatex-paired-parens "$([{")
```

in the `.emacs` file